# Refactoring of the hard code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some API to launch my project, here is the part of code, I want to ask about

```js
getList(oauth2Client).then(items => {
            for (const item of items) {
              if (item.selected && (item.id === 'sib43214@gmail.com' || item.id === 'iva72198@gmail.com')) {
                promiseArray.push(getEvents(oauth2Client, item.id, item.backgroundColor));
              }
            }
```

How can i do the if statement without hard code, I mean change those two specific emails to some common use case.

Comment: Is `items` an array, and is `promiseArray` empty at the beginning? (if so, the code can be made prettier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array or `Set` instead:

```
getList(oauth2Client).then(items => {
  const emails = new Set(['sib43214@gmail.com', 'iva72198@gmail.com']);
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.selected && emails.has(item.id)) {
      promiseArray.push(getEvents(oauth2Client, item.id, item.backgroundColor));
    }
  }
});
```

I'd prefer a `Set` because it has lower complexity, but with an array, use `.includes`:

```
getList(oauth2Client).then(items => {
  const emails = ['sib43214@gmail.com', 'iva72198@gmail.com'];
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.selected && emails.includes(item.id)) {
      promiseArray.push(getEvents(oauth2Client, item.id, item.backgroundColor));
    }
  }
});
```

Or, if you want *any* email address to pass, use a regular expression, something like:

```
getList(oauth2Client).then(items => {
  const emailRe = /^\w+@[a-z0-9]\.[a-z]+$/i;
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.selected && emailRe.test(item.id)) {
      promiseArray.push(getEvents(oauth2Client, item.id, item.backgroundColor));
    }
  }
});
```

(if you want to be even more rigorous, see the [regex here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression))

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need only those 'sib43214@gmail.com', 'iva72198@gmail.com' emails to be correct, i want any email address  to be ok to pass.

Comment: OK, appreciate your help.